# An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket

Tags: sql-server, exception, web-applications

I have a web application with 2 tabs, and on click of each tab, I connect to the database, and fetch some information. Each tab sends a full HTTP Post request to the server and of course, web latency is the nature of web development.

Sometimes when I click rapidly between tabs, change tabs as fast as possible, I get this error from SQL Server:

> A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.)

This is the first time I've seen this error. What's wrong? I'm using LINQ to SQL to connect to DB and nothing fancy is in action. I just have an ordinary web application.

Comment: UIs should never allow users to "spam" database requests

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your handlers for the tab change are breaking your connection to the DB. Consider disabling your tabs while you're processing your requests and you should solve this.